# How to calculate uptime % or Downtime % in Prometheus Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, micrometer

How to calculate uptime in % already in prometheus grafana using below query process_uptime_seconds{application="$application", instance="$instance", job!="jobid"}

Answer (score 3):

For `up` could you do something like this?

```
(1 - avg_over_time(up[1d])) * 86400
```

That would give you the number of seconds down over the last day.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to use that metric to calculate uptime. The fact that the number reset, just means that the process restarted.

Instead I would recommend using the `up` metric that Prometheus creates automatically. Then you would want to group it by application and ignore the instance and jobid.

Something like:

```
sum(up{application="$application"} == 1) by (application) /
 sum(up{application="$application"}) by (application)
```

That way you are dividing how many are succeeding in being up by the total of that application.

Comment: unfortunately the  line  " sum(up{application="$application"} == 1) by (application)" is not working and i am getting an syntax error. Also I am not able to find up metric through application instead i used instance

Comment: Since `up` is a special metric that prometheus creates based on when it scrapes instances, the label `application` will only appear if it is present during Prometheus' scraping and/or relabeling.

I'm not certain what your syntax error is, since it is working for me.

Comment: can I use instance and job to calculate? also can you share the exact expression for calculating uptime %, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Fun fact, this also works if you're using Grafana-cloud-agent!